# jQuery: Clearing Form Inputs on Html.TextBox and then refreshing page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have found this JSFiddle that clear text from input? http://jsfiddle.net/xavi3r/D3prt/

How do I use this for Html.TextBox in razor View in MVC and then refresh page?

So far my solution is this (it works):

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    //this part clean text from textboxes
    $('#button').click(function () {
        $(':input', '#form')
            .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
            .val('')
            .removeAttr('checked')
            .removeAttr('selected');
    });
    //this part submit my search button - it is like refresh button, returns state as it was in begin - this is the same as I click on search without entering parameters
    $('#button').click(function () {
        document.myForm.onSubmit.click();
    });
});
</script>

using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "LoginUser", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "form", name = "myForm"}))
{
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.TextBox("order", Model.Search.Order, new { placeholder="Luška št.", id ="quantity1", @class="quantity form-control"})

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="onSubmit">Search</button>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Clear" id="button" />  

</div>
}
```

In _Layout:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Realy thanks for help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view will be rendered like this as html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="order" id="quantity1" placeholder="Luška št." class="quantity form-control" value="SomeValue" />
    <input type="button" />
</div>
```

and you can do it with this code:

```
$(function () {

    $('.form-group input:button').click(function () {
        $('input#quantity1').val('');
    });

});
```

Comment: it is not working, shoud I put more something on form?

Comment: have you included jquery library?

Comment: you mean <script> ...-jquery2.1.1...<script>?

Comment: then I did include :)

Comment: can you show what have you written by updating your question

Comment: can you check by putting alert in jquery event that it is called or not?

Comment: I have update my code with possible solution - it works, but can you check me if this is proper solution. Realy thanks